# Backquote in lsblk output

Tags: linux, command-line

What does `` ` `` mean in this output from `lsblk`?

[image: lsblk output -click me!]

Answer (score 3):

It's just supposed to represent the "corner" of a tree branch.

On systems with Unicode support (LANG=*.UTF-8), lsblk would actually print the tree [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeXmc.png):

```
NAME     MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda        8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sda1     8:1    0   256M  0 part  /boot
├─sda2     8:2    0     2G  0 part  
│ └─swap 254:1    0     2G  0 crypt [SWAP]
└─sda3     8:3    0 928.7G  0 part  
  └─sys  254:0    0 928.7G  0 crypt /
```

However, if Unicode is unavailable (usually because your system's locale settings are incomplete), programs have to use alternative methods. Many of them just use plain ASCII alternatives, e.g. `` `-- `` or `'--` or `+--` to represent a bottom-left corner.

(VT100-compatible terminals actually can draw the box/line characters without needing Unicode support, but doing that is a bit more complex and not always reliable.)